# Reference to "famous Tchirnaus transformation"

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, fractional-calculus

On page 7 of André Galligo's paper [Deformation of Roots of Polynomials via Fractional
Derivatives](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00653770/document), we find the following statement:

> **Lemma 1**. Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$, then $P_f (x, q) := \frac{1}{n!} x^q \,\Gamma(n − q)\operatorname{Diff}^q (f)$ is a
>   polynomial in $x$ and $q$, of total degree $n$. Notice that, for an
>   initial value $a \in \mathbb{R}$, the polynomial can be written in the
>   basis formed by the powers of $(x − a)$, then one considers the
>   fractional derivative operator $\operatorname{Diff}^q_a$ and the
>   corresponding polynomial $P_{f,a}(x, q)$. Here we set $a = 0$.     We
>   decided that, since we focus on the polynomial roots of a fixed
>   univariate polynomial $f$, it is convenient to choose for $a$ the mean
>   of the complex roots of $f$. Equivalently, **thanks to the famous
>   Tchirnaus transformation**, after a real translation on the abscissa
>   $x$ we can assume that the coefficient of $x^{n−1}$ vanishes, hence
>   the mean of the roots of $f$ is $0$. This last property is also true
>   for all derivatives with integer orders of $f$.

Clearly if $x^{n-1}$ vanishes then the mean of the roots will be $0$ since the sum of roots will be zero by Vieta's Formulas.

However, I have no idea what the supposedly "famous Tchirnaus transformation" is, and I cannot find a single decent reference to it outside of this paper. Does anyone have an idea concerning what this transformation is?

Comment: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Tschirnhausen_transformation

Comment: @symplectomorphic fantastic and concise reference - better than the wikipedia page Quid linked for as simple a purpose as this in my opinion. Thank you symplectomorphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more common spelling is "Tschirnhaus."

See for example   [Tschirnhaus transfromation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tschirnhaus_transformation)

Comment: Wonderful. I'm amazed that Google refused to show me that page given how close the spelling is. Thank you very much Quid - I will accept when able.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes it's a bit surprising that it did not bubble up. I am not sure if the spelling "Tchirnaus" is a real alternative spelling/transliteration. At first I thought so, but now I tend to think it's just an error. But I believe the spelling is natural based on French pronunciation and spelling. One finds it a handful of times.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the Tschirnhausen transformation they refer to is just replacing $x$ by $y = x+a$ for a suitable choice of $a$ to make $y$ satisfy a degree $n$ polynomial with no $y^{n-1}$ term.